# Regular Expression to Find String C#

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-4.0

I want to match string like `<word>~`, `<word>~0.1`, `<word>~0.9` from my string.

But it should not match if it is within double quotes like `"<word>~0.5"` or `"<word>"~0.5`.

A few examples:

```
"World Terror"~10 AND music~0.5                --> should match music~0.5
"test~ my string"                              --> should not match
music~ AND "song remix" AND "world terror~0.5" --> should match music~
```

I have applied below regex for now `\w+~` , but it also matches if the match is contained within quotation marks.

Can please anybody help me on this?

Comment: You need to use negative lookbehind and lookahead. Google them.

Comment: This is complicated. I assume that you also wouldn't want to match `"foo bar~10 baz"`, right? Well, it can be done in a regex, but I'd like to know first if your quoted strings could ever contain escaped quotes (like `\"`)?

Comment: @Barmar: This is way too complicated for someone who doesn't know regexes. Googling won't help him here, StackOverflow can.

Comment: @TimPietzcker, you are correct , it should not match as in your given example  `"foo bar~10 baz"` , and almost there are less possibility that quoted string itself contain escaped characters , but if it is there we can't deny it.

Comment: @Barmar , i have googled it and tried few examples also , but i didn't get succeed.

Comment: @TimPietzcker again you are correct... it looks tough for users like me :(

Comment: why this question is voted as 'not constructive' ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for strings that don't contain escaped quotes (because those would throw the counting for an even number of quotes off-balance):

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(
    @"\w+~[\d.]*  # Match an alnum word, tilde, optional digits/dots
    (?=           # only if there follows...
     [^""]*       # any number of non-quotes
     (?:          # followed by...
      ""[^""]*    # one quote, and any number of non-quotes
      ""[^""]*    # another quote, and any number of non-quotes
     )*           # any number of times, ensuring an even number of quotes
     [^""]*       # Then any number of non-quotes
     $            # until the end of the string.
    )             # End of lookahead assertion", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

If escaped quotes need to be addressed, it gets a bit more complicated:

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(
    @"\w+~[\d.]*         # Match an alnum word, tilde, optional digits/dots
    (?=                  # only if there follows...
     (?:\\.|[^\\""])*    # any number of non-quotes (or escaped quotes)
     (?:                 # followed by...
      ""(?:\\.|[^\\""])* # one quote, and any number of non-quotes
      ""(?:\\.|[^\\""])* # another quote, and any number of non-quotes
     )*                  # any number of times, ensuring an even number of quotes
     (?:\\.|[^\\""])*    # Then any number of non-quotes
     $                   # until the end of the string.
    )                    # End of lookahead assertion", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll check it out and back to you soon :)

Comment: Thanks @Tim Pietzcker, I tested your first regex and it worked exactly what i wanted. :). and again thanks for second regex, I'll lookout it as well. :)